# Swift 3 compiler displays wrong message when returning a value from a void function

Tags: swift, return, swift3

Normally, if you write this code;

```
func test1() {
    return CGPoint.zero
}
```

The compiler will tell you

> unexpected non-void return value in void function

which is very nice. Everyone knows what they did wrong.

But this code will cause the compiler to say something different:

```
func test2() {
    let a: CGFloat = 1
    return CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: a)
}
```

The compiler now says:

> cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGPoint' with an argument list of type '(x: Double, y: CGFloat)'
>
> note: overloads for 'CGPoint' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat), (x: Double, y: Double)

Now I am confused.

Why doesn't the compiler mention *anything* about returning a value in a void function, and instead complain about calling `CGPoint.init` with `(x: 0.0, y: a)`, which is *completely fine*?

Since `0.0` is a float literal, and `CGFloat` conforms to `BinaryFloatingPoint` which conforms to `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`, `0.0` is converted to `CGFloat` at compile time. As a result, the `CGPoint(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)` initializer should have been used. Why does the compiler complain that `CGPoint` can't be initialized with `(x: Double, y: CGFloat)`?

I thought this was because the compiler saw that I was returning a value where I shouldn't and stopped evaulating the expression so `0.0` is not converted to `CGFloat`. But if that's the case, the compiler should have said *something* about returning a value in a void function!

Is this a bug or intended?

Comment: There are (at least) three overloads for `CGPoint(x:, y:)`. It seems that the compiler tries to find one returning `Void`, fails, and then emits that error message.

Comment: I see now! Thank you! @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGPoint` has three overloaded initializers with the same argument names:

```
 public init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
 public init(x: Double, y: Double)
 public init(x: Int, y: Int)
```

You'll get the same error message with

```
let v: Void = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2)
// error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGPoint' with an argument list of type '(x: Double, y: Int)'
// note: overloads for 'CGPoint' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (x: Int, y: Int), (x: Double, y: Double)
```

Here is another example demonstrating the effect:

```
struct A {
    init(x: Double, y: Double) { }
}

struct B {
    init(x: Double, y: Double) { }
    init(xi: Int, yi: Int) { }
}

struct C {
    init(x: Double, y: Double) { }
    init(x: Int, y: Int) { }
}

let v1: Void = A(x: 1, y: 2.0)
// error: cannot convert value of type 'A' to specified type 'Void' (aka '()')

let v2: Void = B(x: 1, y: 2.0)
// error: cannot convert value of type 'B' to specified type 'Void' (aka '()')

let v3: Void = C(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
// error: cannot convert value of type 'C' to specified type 'Void' (aka '()')

let v4: Void = C(x: 1, y: 2.0)
// error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'C' with an argument list of type '(x: Int, y: Double)'
```

Only in the last line, `C(x: 1, y: 2.0)` matches *two* initializers.
I *assume* that the compiler tries to match against both, fails to convert
the return value to `Void` in both cases, and therefore emits a different
error message.

The error message is not very helpful, so you might consider to file
a bug report at http://bugs.swift.org.

Comment: I understand now. I will do a bug report!